# What's a good example of replica set failover / reconnect code for MongoDB / Mongoose 3.x using auth?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication, mongoose

I am simulating MongoDB replica set step-downs and trying to have my application and driver automatically use the new primary member without having to restart my application. Right now, once the step down occurs, a query hangs and eventually times out.

Can someone share some example code of a properly configured replica set connection string that works with Mongoose 3.x and recent version of the mongodb-node-native driver (1.1.2)?

**Please note**: I am using authentication. It is a 2 Node + 1 Arbiter setup.

Comment: Have you tried to perform the same query in the mongo shell?

A timeout implies that your having connection issues. Doing it in the shell will act as an isolation test.

Can you post the node.js connection string and any more information about your configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to mongoose 3.0.2 which has the fix for the 3.x release.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the fix. Much appreciated.